# Selecting meta tags with Selenium

Tags: c#, html, selenium

I want to extract data from a meta tag but the tag is as follows

```
<meta property="og:description" content="blah"/>
```

Since there is no id/class/etc. I can't use

```
driver.FindElement(By.[id/class/etc.]);
```

This meta tag has a unique property and content so I am wondering if there is any better way to locate and extract the content than selecting all "meta" tags and iterating through them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While extracting data from a meta tag, I would suggest to use the attributes as much as possible. In your case :

- **`XPath:`**

  ```
  driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//meta[@property='og:description' and @content='blah']"));
  ```
- **`CssSelector:`**

  ```
  driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("meta[property='og:description'][content='blah']"));
  ```

Answer (score 2):

You can use xPath to grab the specified meta tag

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//meta[@property='og:description']"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this xpaths

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//meta[contains(@property,'og:description']"));
```

or

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//meta[contains(@property,'og:description') and contains(@content,'blah')]"));
```